# Why does this httpwebrequest get a 403 forbidden when same URL works in browser?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I am using a simple webservice and issuing a GET request, if I use a browser or postman with the same URL as I am using in my code I get the correct response, but my code gets a 403 Forbidden and I cannot figure out why

The minimum amount to reproduce the problem below

I verified that the URL passed is correct and I even copied and pasted from the log and the url works in browser and postma.

What can I do?

```
static public async Task<JObject> SimpleGetRequest(string apiUrl)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(apiUrl);
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string apiReturnStr = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
                JObject apiReturnObject = JObject.Parse(apiReturnStr);
                return apiReturnObject;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The request consists of http headers and the default headers are different in c# from postman.  To get your code working use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture postman request.  Then same with c#.  Compare headers and make c# code look exactly like the postman request.

Comment: This cannot reproduce the problem. You should post the API's Uri, with some details on what is required to access that service (Tokens, Keys etc.). It's also useful to know what .Net framework you're using and from what system/version this request is issued. Test it adding a User-Agent header (sometimes it's mandatory). Use the IE11 header (there's a reason). Also, add a CookieContainer. If it's not required, it may help when debugging.

Comment: @Jimi user agent did the trick if you make it an answer I will accept it